# Get mp3/pdf files using JSoup in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, jsoup, crawler4j

I am developing an application for crawling the web using crawler4j and Jsoup. I need to parse a webpage using JSoup and check if it has zip files, pdf/doc and mp3/mov file available as a resource for download.

For zip files i did the following and it works:

```
Elements zip = doc.select("a[href\$=.zip]")
        println "No of zip files is " + zip.size()
```

This code correctly tells me how many zip files are there in a page. I am not sure how to count all audio files or document files using JSoup. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same approach I suspect it would be something like this:

```
Elements docs = doc.select("a[href\$=.doc]")
        println "No of doc files is " + docs.size() 

Elements mp3s = doc.select("a[href\$=.mp3]")
        println "No of mp3 files is " + mp3s.size()
```

Really it's just a selector where the href attribute ends in some file extension.

Comment: thanks . I thought so but the fact that different webpages uses different approaches to embed audio files bothers me. For example, I checked this page : http://mp3.com/top-downloads/ and it has <a relsong> tag for embedding mp3 files. do you think this would not cause incorrect counts?

Comment: Yep, it sure would. You would need a different selector for that a[relSong\$=.mp3] for instance.

Comment: In that way there are several ways people embed mp3s and doc files. Is there any generic way using Jsoup where I can extract the correct information without delving into individual embedding styles?